# Google Customer Reviews form on Magento 1.9.3 not showing at Success Page

Tags: magento1.9.3, order-success-page, google, merchant

My success.phtml dir is -> /app/design/frontend/pb/default/template/checkout  (my theme's success.phtml)

I've tried to implement this code in to this success page.

```
    <!-- BEGIN GCR Opt-in Module Code -->
<?php
$orderId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastOrderId();
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);
?>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js?onload=renderOptIn" async defer></script>

<script>
    window.renderOptIn = function() {
        window.gapi.load('surveyoptin', function() {
            window.gapi.surveyoptin.render(
                {
                    "merchant_id": 112592416,
                    "order_id": "<?php echo $order->getIncrementId() ?>",
                    "email": <?php echo $order->getCustomerEmail() ?>,
                    "delivery_country":  "<?php echo $order->getShippingAddress()->getCountryId() ?>",
                    "estimated_delivery_date": "YYYY-MM-DD",

                });
        });
    }
</script>
<!-- END GCR Opt-in Module Code -->
```

And then I tried. The form is not showed up. I don't know how to configure estimated delivery day but it is usually in 1 day.

I'm stuck at this point and I need a hand :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this line:

```
"email": <?php echo $order->getCustomerEmail() ?>,
```

into

```
"email": "<?php echo $order->getCustomerEmail() ?>",
```

or, copy and past (check your Merchant ID):

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js?onload=renderOptIn" async defer></script>
<script>
window.renderOptIn = function(){
    window.gapi.load('surveyoptin', function(){
        window.gapi.surveyoptin.render({
          "merchant_id": 112592416,
          "order_id": "<?php echo $order->getIncrementId(); ?>",
          "email": "<?php echo $order->getCustomerEmail(); ?>",
          "delivery_country": "<?php echo $order->getShippingAddress()->getCountryId(); ?>",
          "estimated_delivery_date": "<?php $date = date('Y-m-d'); $mod_date = strtotime($date.'+ 1 days'); echo date('Y-m-d',$mod_date); ?>"
        });
    });
}
</script>
```